# How to bind nested model property to kendo grid column?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, telerik, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a model which includes a property of datatype list of another model as below.

```
public class Eatables
{
 int id {get;set;}
 string name{get;set;}
 List<Ingredient> ingredientList{get;set;}
}

public class Ingredient
{
 int id {get;set;}
 quantity {get;set;}
 calories {get;set;}
}
```

if I want to display the list of eatables with their ingredient required as per below kendo header.

```
SL.No | Eatable | Sugar(KG) | Salt(gram) | Oil(L)
```

I am passing List of eatables to the view which is consumed in displaying the kendo list if sugar ingredient id is 2 and salt ingredient id is 4 I have below column bound LINQ query to fetch the quantity of the ingredient as below.

```
columns.Bound(x => x.ingredientList.Find(x=>x.id=="2").quantity) -- to fetch sugar quantity
columns.Bound(x => x.ingredientList.Find(x=>x.id=="4").quantity) -- to fetch salt quantity
```

But the above queries are not fetching the quantity though the values are available in the model being sent from the controller. 
please suggest if I am missing anything the query, it been a day I am in a maze to fix the issue.

Comment: Hi. Checkout this [code sample](http://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/templating/client-detail-template)

Comment: @shahareldad, I am not looking for a nested kendo grid let me know if there is a way to fetch nested modal property as per the kendo header above

Comment: Your view model property name is ingredientlist and in the view you are referring to ingredients, is this a mistake or it is the actual code?

Comment: is it a typo: your 'Eatables' class has `ingredientList`, but you use `ingredients` in kendo grid?

Comment: I would create a ViewModel that flattens that out with properties called SugarAmt, SaltAmt, OilAmt, etc. Then build those in your action and bind your grid columns to those properties.

Comment: @SteveGreene I think that should be the solution because the kendo grid accepts only the flat model.

Answer (score 1):

As it is mentioned in the comments too a way to handle this is to flatten the model since the kendo grid is designed to [work with flat data](https://www.telerik.com/forums/how-to-display-list-object-count-in-a-cell).
Let's say we will use the ViewModel EatableSSOVM

```
public class EatableSSOViewModel
{
   public int id {get;set;}
   public string name{get;set;}
   public string sugar {get; set;}
   public string salt{get; set;}
   public string oil{get; set;}
}
```

Map with your LINQ Queries the values of sugar, salt and oil and bind your grid to the `List<EatableSSOViewModel>`

According however to this [link](https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/faq#how-to-customize-the-way-properties-are-displayed-in-grid-bound-columns) which talks about client templates of the grid, one option could be to do something like the following

```
columns.Template( @<text>
     @item.ingredientList.Find(x=>x.id=="2").quantity
    </text>
);
```

Inside the template you could write Razor syntax and pretty much do a lot of things that would result to a string input that the column could bind to.